# How to host different routes on different servers?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web-applications, react-router, serverless

I am building a web application, where different routes should be hosted separately. So let us say I have `abc.com` this will be on server 1, abc.com/serviceA will be on server 2 and abc.com/serviceB will be on server 3. I was planning on using AWS to achieve this requirement. So, I would really appreciate if I can design this using AWS services and React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [application Load balancer host-based routing.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) and path based routing.

All you need to declare two targets for your two servers, suppose traffic of `abc.com` this host will route to target group A, and traffic from  `abc.com/service` path will route to service B.

[image]

[image]

Or if you want path base routings like `abc.com/server1/*` or `abc.com/v2/*` then you case use path base routing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either achieve this by placing an [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of your services, or an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html). Either of those can achieve what you describe.

If you also want to do things like rate-limiting clients, issuing API keys, or allowing users to login with social media accounts like Google or Facebook (among many other features) then you should look into API Gateway and possibly Amazon Cognito.